# meaning of someclass <VH extends ???>

Tags: android, firebase

I know JAVA's generic concept  = type 
and Android's Recycler View concept.

I already know this -> extends RecyclerView.Adapter. have seen from the Android developer site.

But, this is still difficult to understand.

I was looking at Firebase's Cloud Firestore code.

And some codes...

```
extends FirestoreAdapter<SomeClassAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

and

```
public abstract class FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
```

these concepts are so difficult for me...
some generics and something extends in there.

I've done a lot of searches and I've done a lot of thinking. Can you explain easily, please?? or some sites to refer.

Thanks for reading! any kind of tip does not matter. I`ll appreciate!

Comment: To simplify things it's just means that you can only use a subclass of `ViewHolder` as argument. If the class is not `ViewHolder` then it will not compile.

Comment: Enzokie thanks, and why it extends for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to understand if I explain this with an example:

Assume we have an adapter class named `SomeClassAdapter` which has an inner class called `ItemViewHolder` as below:

```
public class SomeClassAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter {
    ...
    private class ItemViewHolder extends FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder {
    ...
    }
}
```

If we want to extend `SomeClassAdapter` using the inner class (`ItemViewHolder`) as our view holder we would use:

```
public class Example extends FirestoreAdapter<SomeClassAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
```

But the second concept you mentioned is the super class which we extend in our example (it's abstract and we have to extend it and override its abstract methods in order to make an instance)

Now assume we have a class which requires a type to use it across the class declaration. In that case we declare a class like `FirestoreAdapter` and pass the generic type inside `<..>` like: `FirestoreAdapter<VH>`. In case we need our `VH` to be a sub type of another class like `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` we declare it as: `FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`.

And what if we need our `FirestoreAdapter` itself to be a sub type of another class such as `RecyclerView.Adapter`? So it would be `FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
extends RecyclerView.Adapter`. In our example the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class needs a generic type extending `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` itself and we want to use the same type we used for `FirestoreAdapter<VH>` here so we simply pass `VH` as our generic type for `RecyclerView.Adapter`. And to come into a conclusion we'll have:

```
FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
```

Comment: Thanks! but I know the abstract things, but <VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>This part is the most difficult sentence.

Comment: @marsho see my edited answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: so appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

#### Immediate translation.

Translated to human speak we get this, The generic FirestoreAdapter will only except parameterized types of ViewHolder or its subclasses. Finally it will inherit all of the available fields from its super class, which is the generic class RecyclerView.Adapter

- Proof and documentation is down below.

**< VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder >**

- This is part is utilizing [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

#### Why use Bounded Type Parameters?

- Well the documentation states:

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type.

- Before we move on it is important that we define type **type arguments** and **parameterized type**

##### What are type arguments?

- As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) :

> Many developers use the terms "type parameter" and "type argument" interchangeably, but these terms are not the same. When coding, one provides type arguments in order to create a parameterized type.

- We can then map this definition over to our code to understand that our own CustomAdapter.ViewHolder acts as a type arguments . Now we can move on.

##### What is a parameterized type?

- Well the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) states

> We can think of parameterized types as formal instantiations of our type arguments To instantiate this class, use the new keyword, as usual, but place  between the class name and the parenthesis:
> Box integerBox = new Box();

#### What is < VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder > doing?

- The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) states :

> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound

- Now type parameters are simply anything that goes inside the angle brackets <>. [Source](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-12/1-type-parameters)
- With that being said we can come to the conclusion that **VH** is nothing more that a type parameter and **extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder** is saying that our generic class only accepts ViewHolder objects or its subclasses.

### Conclusion

**public abstract class FirestoreAdapter
extends RecyclerView.Adapter**

- translates to, The generic FirestoreAdapter will only except parameterized types of ViewHolder or its subclasses. Finally it will inherit all of the available fields from its super class which is the generic class RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: gorgeous answer dude